# Tally repeated evaluation of function

Tags: functions

How can I tally the result of repeated evaluation of a function?

```
n=100000;
f[]:=RandomInteger[{1, 4}]
Tally@Table[f[], {n}]
```

When `n` is really big this needs an unnecessary amount of memory, how do I get rid of the `Table` without slowing it down significantly?

```
fTally[f_, n_] := Module[{ c },
  c[_] = 0;
  Do[c[#] += 1 & @ f[], {n}];
  Most[DownValues[c] /. HoldPattern[_@c[y_] :> m_] :> {y, m}]
  ]
AbsoluteTiming[fTally[f, n];]              (* 0.6s   *)
AbsoluteTiming[Tally@Table[f[], {n}];]     (* 0.009s *)
```

Comment: I suspect you will not be able to approach the speed of `Tally` with a user-defined function (outside of compilation, which restricts type).  Nevertheless I'll try.

Comment: Regarding your update, try: `Do[c[#] += 1 & @ f[], {n}]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That fixes it, why was it wrong?

Comment: Take a look at `Trace[c[f[]] +=1 ]` -- there's a double evaluation of `f[]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This is because of `Increment` which is `HoldFirst`.

Comment: Ouch, thanks! Fixed in question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A systematic approach seems to be in using iterators. An iterator is a data structure which returns a given part of a list on demand. Here is a possible implementation for the case at hand:

```
ClearAll[makeIterator];
makeIterator[f_, chunkSize_, n_] :=
  Module[{ctr = 0},
    iterator[
       Function[
        If[ctr >= n,
          None,
          With[{result = Table[f[], {Min[chunkSize, n - ctr]}]},
            ctr += Length[result];
            result
          ]]]]];
```

We need to add one generic method for an iterator:

```
ClearAll[getNext];
getNext[iterator[f_]] := f[]
```

To test, you can define e.g.

```
iter = makeIterator[f, 10, 105]
```

and then call `getNext[iter]` a few times.

The next ingredient is an auxiliary function which I will call `merge`:

```
ClearAll[merge];
merge[tally1_, tally2_] :=
  Transpose[{#[[All, 1, 1]], Total[#[[All, All, 2]], {2}]}] &@
     GatherBy[tally1~Join~tally2, First]
```

this merges the counts of two different tallied lists. Finally:

```
lazyTally[i_iterator] := 
  FixedPoint[
    With[{next = getNext[i]}, 
      If[next === None, #, merge[#, Tally@next]]
    ] &,
    {}]
```

We can benchmark:

```
AbsoluteTiming[fTally[f,n];]              
AbsoluteTiming[Tally@Table[f[],{n}];]    
lazyTally[makeIterator[f,1000,n]]//AbsoluteTiming

 (*
    {0.3583984,Null}
    {0.0058593,Null}
    {0.0156250,{{4,24811},{1,24963},{3,25233},{2,24993}}}
 *)
```

You get a 100-fold efficiency gain in memory for about 3-fold loss in runtime efficiency, for this size of the chunk of entire list (which you can play with)

Comment: That's it, I'm going to bed.  You're making my head hurt trying to think this through. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Have a good sleep :)

Comment: Great! I like the idea of an iterator to do the chunking

Comment: @ssch Iterators represent a very simple for of inversion of control. They allow one to still give the control to actual higher-level functions which do the computations, and which can demand new elements as they need them. They help making the code more modular, since there is then no direct coupling between the computing routines and specific functions which produce list's elements.

Answer (score 3):

It is still far slower than `Tally` but `Sum` appears to be faster than your `fTally`:

```
n = 1000000;
f[] := RandomInteger[{1, 4}]

fTally[f, n]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 2.0300028

```
Sum[inert[f[]], {n}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.8900012

The output is in this form:

> ```
> 249831 inert[1] + 250045 inert[2] + 250386 inert[3] + 249738 inert[4]
> ```

I am still exploring options but if I find none better I shall package this into a function that produces output of the form used by `Tally`.

---

Below this point are some rambling observations as I make them.

`Table` is faster than `Do` with your test function:

```
n = 1000000;
Table[f[], {n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
Do[f[], {n}];    // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0410001, Null}
>
> {0.2300003, Null}

This is probably due to compilation:

```
SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "TableCompileLength"]
```

> ```
> {"CompileOptions" -> {"TableCompileLength" -> 250}}
> ```

Comment: Since `f` is defined via rules, it is not likely to be auto-compiled.

Comment: @Leonid well, it's auto-*somethinged* as setting `"TableCompileLength" -> Infinity` causes the `Table` evaluation to slow down to match `Do`.  What's your alternative explanation for that?