# Running out of memory when filtering a large data set

Tags: export, data

My goal is to read `list0.dat`, filter the data with a function `f`, and then write the transformed data to `list1.dat`, as in the following:

```
input = <<list0.dat;
output = Map[f[#]&, input];
output >> list1.dat;
```

However, `input` and `output` are both very large lists. (The format is just the usual anlytical expression.) So "No more memory available" always appears. How can I deal with this problem? I need some suggestions for memory control and how to export the transformed data to an external file in real time.

Comment: Are you sure that f[ ] functions correctly? If you calculate the above lines with a list0.dat that has only 5 entries, does it work? Check the MemoryInUse function and see how it scales with the length of your input list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16048/how-do-you-deal-with-very-large-datasets-in-mathematica)?

Comment: [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19267/efficient-code-for-tallying-entries-in-very-large-lists/19269#19269) I provide an explicit worked-out example of solving a similar problem. Not sure if this one is a duplicate of that or other mentioned candidates.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin  Thanks! In my case, essentially, I just transform a large math expression  to another a large expressions. Can you give me some suggestions？

Comment: If your expression is very large, it may make sense to have some serialization mechanism, so that its parts can be read separately. In general, doing this in chunks, similar to what was suggested by Mr.Wizard, on in my linked answer, seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is merely a skeleton answer.  I will leave you to implement these ideas as without knowing your data format I cannot give usable code.

- Open an input [stream](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StreamsAndLowLevelInputAndOutput.html) with [`OpenRead`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OpenRead.html), and an output stream with [`OpenWrite`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OpenWrite.html) or [`OpenAppend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OpenAppend.html).
- Read a block of a manageable size from the input stream using `ReadList`
- Process this data and apply your function
- Format the data, if necessary, and write with [`Write`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Write.html) or [`WriteString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WriteString.html)
- Detect the end of the input file; see [`EndOfFile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EndOfFile.html).
- [`Close`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Close.html) the input and output streams.

Alternatively you could use [`PutAppend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PutAppend.html) rather than an output stream; this may be more convenient depending on what format you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in version 9, there is a function called `ImageFileFilter` which applies any function `f` to all the pixels of an image, without reading the whole image into memory. So if your data happened to be an image your problem would be solved. But of course an image is just an array of numbers, so another strategy you could consider would be to convert your data into one of the standard image formats, apply `ImageFileFilter` to the converted data, and then convert back into your preferred data format.

Comment: I like this idea - have you ever demonstrated or got this working - say creating an array of numbers and processing it as PNG or TIFF or JPEG?

Comment: @cormullion -- Not in the offline setting... meaning I often translate between `Image` format and `Imagedata` format in Mathematica's working memory, but have never actually tried it on disk.