# How to make a reducer in mathematica (mapreduce)

Tags: data-acquisition

I want to make a toy mapreduce demonstration in Mathematica using iterator.
Iterator allows to  simulate real case when we get input row by row, not nowing in advance how many rows are there in source.
Consider the simple job known as Words Count.
Each row is represented by a word in the text.
We may simulate a text as `list = {foo, foo, quux, labs, foo, bar, quux}.`

To simulate row-by-row throwing of words the following iterator is fine [[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135916/how-to-use-the-iterator-in-mathematica)]:

```
ClearAll[mIterator];
mIterator[fname_Symbol, a_List] :=
  With[{indices = a},
   With[{len  = Length[indices]},
    Module[{i = 0},
      ClearAll[fname];
      fname[] := With[{ind = ++i}, indices[[ind]] /; ind <= len];
      fname[] := Null;
 ]]];
```

We write:

```
mIterator[next, Thread[{{foo, foo, quux, labs, foo, bar, quux}, {1,1,1,1,1,1,1}}]]
```

Each `next[]` will return {"word", 1}, thus we simulate a `mapper` job. 
What I need is a `reducer`. (To be certain sorter and reducer at once as output of `mIterator` is not sorted.)

How to make a [reducer](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/) function that takes the output of `mIterator` and returns (prints or saves to a dictionary):

```
bar     1
foo     3
labs    1
quux    2
```

? 
Limitation. Reducer does not know how may rows mapper will produce. I now realize that the question concerns procedural style, but even in 
"Mathematica Gets Big Data with HadoopLink" (`blog.wolfram.com/2013/07/31/mathematica-gets-bigdata-with-hadooplink/`) procedural style is used.

Comment: Check [`Tally`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html) and [`Counts`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Counts.html).

Comment: @Kuba, is it better now?

Comment: @io_tuta Don't know if enough to get answers you look for but better, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient code for tallying entries in very large lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19267/efficient-code-for-tallying-entries-in-very-large-lists)

Comment: Also see [18813](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18813/tally-repeated-evaluation-of-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to understand why you want to proceed with an awkward procedural approach when Mathematica has elegant built-in functional methods accomplish your goal. The built-in function `Tally` can do the job of both your producer and reducer on a list of words of arbitrary length. For example,

```
Tally[{"foo", "foo", "quux", "labs", "foo", "bar", "quux"}]
```

> `{{"foo", 3}, {"quux", 2}, {"labs", 1}, {"bar", 1}}`

It is simple to write a function so the result is a dictionary.

```
toDictionary[words : {_String ..}] := AssociationThread @@ Transpose[Tally[words]]

toDictionary[{"foo", "foo", "quux", "labs", "foo", "bar", "quux"}]
```

> `<|"foo" -> 3, "quux" -> 2, "labs" -> 1,  "bar" -> 1|>`